# Some doubts about a simple Swing listener code

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am studying Java Swing and listener use and I have some problems with the following simple code:

```
package com.mycompany.experiment;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ListenerExp1 {

    private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // Qui scriviamo il codice che vogliamo eseguire all' azione del
            // click sul pulsante
        }
    }

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));

    JButton button = new JButton("Cliccami");
    MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener();

    button.addActionListener(listener);

}
```

In this code I declare a listener class and I try to create a JFrame and a JButton objects.

The problem is that when I try to add some properties to these objects by the lines:

```
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
```

and

```
button.addActionListener(listener);
```

Eclipse sign me the following error on these 2 lines:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
>     - Syntax error on token "setMinimumSize", = expected after this

What is wrong?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements should be in a code block such as a method a constructor

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));

JButton button = new JButton("Cliccami");
MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener();

button.addActionListener(listener);
```

In addition you want to invoke them in the [`EDT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) like so

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));

            JButton button = new JButton("Cliccami");
            MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener();

            button.addActionListener(listener);
        }
    });
```

Read: [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Or in constructor, yes.

Answer (score 1):

In java, you can not initialize instance without or outside of method.

put following of your code in a method.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 400));

JButton button = new JButton("Cliccami");
MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener();

button.addActionListener(listener);
```